# How would I import my model from blender to unity to look exactly alike?

Tags: texturing, import, unity

How would I import my model from blender to unity to look exactly alike?
I've tried importing the model and setting the material naming to the models material. I then drag and drop the texture into the albedo for both materials.
As you can see by the pictures, the crystal isn't refracting light like it should and the empty face is showing through the transparency. The top image is from blender and the bottom is from unity.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "*import my model from blender to unity*" ? Are you **exporting from Blender and importing in Unity** or are you **exporting from Unity and importing in Blender** ? Either way materials are never transferred, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Exporting from blender and into unity. How would I get a more accurate representation of what the unity rendering would look like in blender? Also, how do I recreate this refraction effect to work better with unity?

Comment: You can't, don't even waste your time. Completely different material system and rendering engines, so don't bother unless utterly necessary. Unwrap and texture your models properly in Blender, export then create your material inside Unity, see the provided link above.